# How to add GEOIP2 module to Nginx on Windows?

Tags: nginx, nginx-config

I have Nginx running on my windows 11 machine. I want to add the geoip2 module so I can block ip by region. I can't seem to find any info online about how to add it to Windows hosted Nginx. Does anyone have an idea? Or is there another better way to block Ips by region?

Thanks!

Comment: My suggestion is to run Nginx in a Docker Linux container. Then you can add the geoip2 modules as a Linux module.